# EditText Last Character Not Deletable

Tags: android

I am having an issue where users with Android OS 4.3 are unable to delete the last character of text added to an EditText item.

This is the code for the EditText Item:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

The java code where I set the editText value is:

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    mEmailView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

    if(settings.contains("username")){
        mEmail = settings.getString("username", " ");
    }

    mEmailView.setText(mEmail, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    mEmailView.setSelection(mEmail.length());
```

Any help solving this issue would be welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: Is there any other code involving the EditText? There must be some place you're assigning a value that's not letting the last character get deleted.

Comment: What exactly is 'unable to delete'? Any error messages?

Comment: There are no error messages.  When a user clicks on the editText item, and hits the back button they are unable to delete the last character shown in the editText item.  I have added the java code to the main post. Thanks!

Comment: Are they able to type additional characters or move the cursor and delete other characters? What if you just use `mEmailView.setText(mEmail);`?

Comment: A user is able to delete any other characters, and add characters.  I have tried using the line of code you suggested and nothing changes.  Furthermore, I have found this issue is not limited to any one OS, but it isn't always present.  I have yet to discover what the circumstances are in which this bug will and won't present itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `mEmailView.setSelection(mEmail.length()-1);`, instead of what you're using.

Comment: This doesn't fix my problem, although this is a good suggestion.  Thanks!